# Open the Public Repository to the VS code image running on my Docker Desktop

Tags: reactjs, go, visual-studio-code, automation

During a project, I encountered an issue in selecting a repository and opening it in the Visual Studio Code, which is running as an open-source image on my Docker Desktop. I have the repository URL, and I'm seeking guidance on how to programmatically open that repository in the Visual Studio Code instance within the Docker Desktop, either using ReactJS or GoLang. How can I achieve this?

I have attempted various approaches, such as cloning the repository locally and manually opening it at any location on my system. Although this method works, I am struggling to automate the process when using a GitHub repository within Visual Studio Code running on Docker Desktop locally.